# add language in python searching google

Tags: python, google-search

How can I add here "lang" "polish" or "pl" so it will search only polish lang results?

```
uQuery_1 = "some words" #@param {type:"string"}
uNum = 10

def getResults(uQuery, uTLD, uNum, uStart, uStop):
  try: 
      from googlesearch import search 
  except ImportError:  
      print("No module named 'google' found") 
  
  # What are we searching for 
  query = uQuery
  
  # Prepare the data frame to store urls
  d = []

  for j in search(query, tld=uTLD, num=uNum, start=uStart, stop=uStop, pause=2): 
      d.append(j)
      print(j)
  return d

results_1 = getResults(uQuery_1, "com", uNum, 1,uNum)
```

Thanks for an answer @kosciej16, but now:
how should I change results? I am trying different combinations and it is still showing "us .com results"

```
results_1 = getResults(uQuery_1, lang, "pl", uNum, 1,uNum) 
results_1 = getResults(uQuery_1, lang, "com", uNum, 1,uNum) 
results_1 = getResults(uQuery_1, "pl", uNum, 1,uNum)
```

?
thanks in advance

Comment: There seems to be a documentatoin for the module googleseach https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/ Might be useful to take a look the section *Additional options*

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Comment: thanks guys for answers, I have edited orginal question

Answer (score 1):

As you can find in [documentation](https://python-googlesearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), lang is just another parameter of `search` method.

```
  for j in search(query, tld=uTLD, num=uNum, start=uStart, stop=uStop, pause=2, lang="pl"): 
      d.append(j)
      print(j)
```